# Prepend sys.path from shell?

Tags: python, shell, path

If You want to use given `python` binary You can prepend `PATH`.

If You want to use given `libpython` You can prepend `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Now suppose You want to use given package directory. I tried `PYTHONPATH` -- but it doesn't work:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.path[:2]'
['', '/home/boris/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
$ PYTHONPATH="/home/boris/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages" python -c 'import sys; print sys.path[:2]'
['', '/home/boris/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

In order to do that You'd have to do either in script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/boris/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

or make the special `usercustomize.py` in default `site-packages` with the same contents.

Is there a way to modify `sys.path` from the shell?

The behaivior I'm looking for is:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.path[:2]'
['', '/home/boris/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
$ your-shell-command
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.path[:2]'
['/home/boris/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '']
```

**Edit**:

I can see no harm if the dir will be second:

```
['', '/home/boris/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

but

```
~: PYTHONPATH="/home/farhad" python -c 'import sys; print sys.path[:2]'
['', '/home/boris/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

doesn't work for me. Probably because I have `usercustomize.py` (see I also want `~/.local` libs before system-wide ones).

Comment: Why do you need to override `''` at all? The local directory is first for a reason.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, [anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/) provides faster numpy in a custom dir, but I don't want to use all the time. So I write a shell command which would switch things from system python and libs to anaconda's python and libs.

Comment: And how is the current behaviour preventing you from doing that? `numpy` isn't installed in the current directory, is it? (Note that the first `sys.path` entry is always the directory of the script being run).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it is installed in the `~/.local/...` -- I compiled it myself.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean you *have* to be listed *first*. Listed second is *more than fine*. All you need is be listed before the system paths.

Comment: You can use `virtualenv` for compiled libraries.

Comment: Your test code actually works fine for me; `PYTHONPATH="/home/boris/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages" python -c 'import sys; print sys.path[:2]'` prints `['', '/home/boris/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`.

Answer (score 1):

For me works:

```
$PYTHONPATH="/home/farhad" python -c 'import sys; print sys.path[:2]'
['', '/home/farhad']
$
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want it listed second, but *first*, so before the `''` (script directory) entry.

Comment: Because the answer isn't helpful. The OP explicitly described what the wrong and right outcomes are and you gave the OP what was already found to be undesirable.

Comment: It could be that I read it wrong though; I see now that the OP is talking about different paths, not sure if there is something else wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your particular use case, as you describe it in the comments, would be covered by making `~/.local/.../numpy` a symlink, and then changing that symlink instead of directly altering the import path.

Comment: Yep. The problem with Your way, is I not only need numpy but some other libs as well (scipy, sympy, matplotlib) etc. I can make a couple of `usercustomize.py` there and swich between them with a shell function (renaming one of them to `usercustomize.py~` interchangebly). I actually did it, but now hope for a better solution.